# Checkbox won't update rendered value in table

Tags: jsf, richfaces

So heres the skinny of it.  I have a rendered tag on my selectOneMenu. I've tried it in various ways, this last one updating the form in the boolean checkbox with the "@form".  I am all out of ideas, been working on it for a few days.  What am I missing so I can render/unrender based on the selection of the checkbox?  Thanks.

```html
<rich:dataTable id="catalogview"  width="100%"  style="width: 100% !important"
    columnClasses="lcolumnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog,columnCatalog" 
    value="#{pcnAlerts.notifications}" var="pcn" rows="20"
    headerClass="headerCatalog" styleClass="table1" footerClass="footer_td" >
    <h:column>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{pcn.checked}" update="@form" >
            <f:ajax listener="#{pcnAlerts.selectItem}" render=":popupForm:popupPanelContents" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">                             
            <h:outputText value="Status" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{pcn.status}" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="StatusMenu" value="#{pcnAlerts.newStatus}" rendered="#{pcn.checked}">
            <a4j:ajax update="StatusMenu"  listener="#{pcnAlerts.saveStatus()}" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="New" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Pending" itemLabel="Pending" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Complete" itemLabel="Complete" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Archive" itemLabel="Archive" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Disregard" itemLabel="Disregard" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must also update `catalogview` in order to render the components inside the table. Also, make sure your `<rich:dataTable>` is inside a `<h:form>`:

```
<h:form id="frmCatalog">
    <rich:dataTable id="catalogview" value="#{pcnAlerts.notifications}" var="pcn">
        <h:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{pcn.checked}">
                <f:ajax listener="#{pcnAlerts.selectItem}"
                    render=":popupForm:popupPanelContents :frmCatalog:catalogview" />
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </h:column>
    </rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Does the form have to be refernced like that in the render?  I tried to update the catalog view, but since it was immediately up I didn't include all that.

Comment: Also, did you mean to put that in render?  I would think that belongs in update, right?

Comment: @user1582340 [`<f:ajax>` doesn't have `update` attribute](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_ajax.html), you mean `render`. AFAIK PrimeFaces components that support ajax functionality has this `update` attribute.

Comment: @user1582340 about the form references in `render`, it's the full id of the `catalogview` component, so there's no problem with it.